# Using CSS !important with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<div id="testDiv">
  <h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>
  <p class="example">A paragraph with class="example".</p>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<style>
  .example {
    background-color: green !important;
  }
</style>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("#testDiv p.example");
    x[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
</script>
```

From the code above, how can I override css property by !important in the above style property from my JS code defined in script tag ?

*Note: We have some internal applications that have their styles declared important*

Comment: Does `style.backgroundColor = "red !important"` not work?

Comment: Nope..when I kept !important that css isn't working bcoz, that's not a correct format.

Comment: In my application I can't use styles by .css files so, I have to use JavaScript code to override the existing code. The code I given above is jst for reference purpose

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Try this code using [CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty):

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("#testDiv p.example");
    x[0].style.setProperty("background-color", "red", "important");
}
```

Comment: @Nagaraju_007 This one though, will only overwrite the specified property, where mine and Pete's solution might overwrite the whole style, so +1 from me ... and test it properly

Comment: I got this @LGSon, If we want to set single property then this was good and if we want to set for some group of properties your code is good..

Comment: Browser support fior this also seems to be not an issue: https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_cssstyledeclaration_setproperty

Answer (score 3):

Here is 2 different script, one target an element's CSS property and the other its style.

```html
<div id="testDiv">
  <h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>
  <p class="example">A paragraph with class="example".</p>
</div>

<p>Click the button to add a background color to the first element in the document with class="example" (index 0).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Try it 2</button>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The querySelectorAll() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("#testDiv p.example");
    x[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("#testDiv p.example");
    x[0].style = "background-color: red !important";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To override an important style in the style sheet you need to set the style attribute with js:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("#testDiv p.example");
  x[0].setAttribute('style', 'background-color: red !important');
}
```

```css
p.example {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="testDiv">
  <h2 class="example">A heading with class="example"</h2>
  <p class="example">A paragraph with class="example".</p>
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```