# Random image generator works in Safari but not Chrome/Firefox

Tags: php, wordpress, random, css-grid

I'm working on a site design and am trying out a homepage design using CSS grid (using Themeco's Pro WP theme) with two different cells assigned unique IDs. I found a way to randomize the background images of each cell by making a PHP function (for what I want to accomplish, background-image seems more appropriate than img), and my code works perfectly in Safari, but the randomization does not work at all in Chrome or Firefox. Chrome and Firefox do act consistently with each other, but oddly, they only show the third item in the $designbg array and only the second item in the $photobg array. Figuring there must be some reason it's breaking in such a specific way, but I can't figure it out.

You can see it in action here:
https://beta.cheshiredave.com

I also tried deleting the three cells other than the ones containing the background images, and the randomization still doesn't work on Chrome/FF EXCEPT that now the images being pulled from the arrays is different: now I get the second item from the $designbg array and the first from the $photobg array. See the difference here:

https://beta.cheshiredave.com/test

Weird side note: also oddly, the words "photography" and "art direction" don't show up on Chrome on Windows, but they do show up as expected on Chrome on Mac. The words appear and behave normally on other Mac/Windows browsers. Making me wonder if something is wonky with assigning IDs to grid cells.

Here's the code:

```
function randomizeBg(){

  $designbg = array('/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/farm.poster.plain_.jpg','/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/maglayout.jpg','/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/farm.blue_.jpg'); // array of filenames

  $dbg = rand(0, count($designbg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedDesignBg = "$designbg[$dbg]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen

  $photobg = array('/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/ginkgo.jpg','/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/amelie.jpg','/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/amelie.red_.jpg'); // array of filenames

  $pbg = rand(0, count($photobg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedPhotoBg = "$photobg[$pbg]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen

  ?>
  
  <style>
  #designside {
    background-image: url(<?php echo $selectedDesignBg; ?>) !important;
    z-index: -9999;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

  #photoside {
    background-image: url(<?php echo $selectedPhotoBg; ?>) !important;
    z-index: -9999;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

</style>
  
  <?php
  
};

add_action( 'x_before_the_content_begin', 'randomizeBg' );
```

In case you're wondering, I have tried the wp_head hook instead already, and I have also tried array_rand; no difference in either case.

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: That's a cache issue. Try navigating using different params like [v1](https://beta.cheshiredave.com/?v1) or [v2](https://beta.cheshiredave.com/?v2) and so on.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would be the case -- I had never loaded those pages into any of the browsers that didn't work until today, and I created the /test page today and it didn't work on the same browsers that the other page didn't work on.

Comment: That actually does work, but then it's stuck on whatever it selected. Is there a way to force the cache to clear? Why does it work fine on Safari but not the others?

Comment: You can use HTTP headers for disabling cache, but I suggest you pick the random image using javascript. You can also make a script that just returns a random image source and of course not cachable snd use that to your CSS `background-image` source.

Comment: I was trying to use JS to do it at first, but I need to redefine the CSS using !important, and it seems that I can't do that with JS, unless I just hadn't figured out how to do it.

Comment: It's pretty easy ``document.getElementById('designside').style.backgroundImage = `url(${Math.round(Math.random() * (images.length - 1))})`;``

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't add !important, which is critical for this to work.

Comment: Really you can't see that you just add it at the end of the string after the `url` closing parentheses? I suggest you take some time to learn some JS basics and how to write inline CSS using JS.

Comment: I'll try -- I was trying to do that a while back but was running into problems trying to get !important into the CSS via JS (like it's not really something JS can do), which is why I turned to PHP instead. I'll try again...

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38454240/using-css-important-with-javascript/38454576 . Also try ``document.getElementById('#designside').style.backgroundImage = `url(...) !important`;``.

Comment: I'll try it -- thanks for the help

Comment: I was able to make it work with JS, even without !important as it turned out -- the key I had been missing was that the code needed to appear AFTER the divs, which I learned from a cautionary note I hadn't seen before when I looked up how to do random div BG images in JS. Thanks for pushing me back to JS.